# How can I remove inline keyboard after click? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

My bot sends a message and two buttons. After the user clicks the + or - button, I want this built-in keyboard to disappear.

Here's how I make the buttons:

```
markup_command = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
btn_p1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='+', callback_data='like')
btn_p2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='-', callback_data='disslike')
markup_command.add(btn_p1, btn_p2)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'choose +/-', reply_markup=markup_command)
```

that's what will happen if you press the button:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'like':
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'like')
```

How can I make this buttons to disappear after the click?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [editmessagereplymarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup)  to edit the keyboard with an empty one